# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87 using ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get selenium to open a site and I don't really have any errors in my PyCharm editor but when I run my code I am getting a lot of errors I do not really understand it would be nice to get some help

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.singaporetech.edu.sg/")  # get gets url
print(driver.title)  # title of the page

driver.close()
```

This is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\kaush\PycharmProjects\seleniumTest1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/kaush/PycharmProjects/seleniumTest1/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaush\PycharmProjects\seleniumTest1\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\kaush\PycharmProjects\seleniumTest1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\kaush\PycharmProjects\seleniumTest1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\kaush\PycharmProjects\seleniumTest1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\kaush\PycharmProjects\seleniumTest1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\kaush\PycharmProjects\seleniumTest1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87
Current browser version is 86.0.4240.198 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Comment: You chromedriver version and chrome version dont match up.

Comment: If you read the last line `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87
    Current browser version is 86.0.4240.198` It says version mismatch. You can refer following link to find compatible version. https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87
    Current browser version is 86.0.4240.198 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=87.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=87.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 87**

- You are using *Chrome* **v86.0.4240.198**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.40* and the *Chrome Browser v85.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v87.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 87.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v87.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/notes.txt)).
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: So there's no kind of backward compatibility....Amazing:O